# Can't set domain name at local provider in order to bind to ip adress of VPS

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, web, dns

I can't handle domain setup. Using some local domains register with a bit complicated setup. On other side I have Digital Ocean server which is sussecfully connected to domain. At Digital Ocean side(VPS provider) side everything must be right(because obvious ) but local domain register settings seem to be incorrect.

Please follow, if you good at the science of the settings domains. At the domain site settings there are kind of default NS servers which are told to be not touched

There are many which look like `nsa2.srv53.net`, `nsa4.srv53.net` and it's told to manage dis at other universal website which is also provided, but this one is totally unclear to me. There ale like different options for different prefixed to domain name like `www.domain` or `@.domain` and different types like A or AAAA or mix, and what is most important - redirect options to set of every row. If I redirect to the very `domain` I would get the following error.

```
too many redirections
```

If I set ip adress, I get redirect to ip, not domain name in url(WRONG). But Digital Ocean tutorials say to set there servers name at domain register but I have no idea where (`like ns1.digitalocean.com, ns2.digitalocean.com`). Please help to puzzle out. Previously used simpler services like namecheap, where it was easy

Comment: It is understandable that you are confused, but it is difficult to answer if there is no question.

Comment: @DusanBajic the question what should I  set there, in order to get correct redirect to domain url)

Comment: OK. You have server in DigitalOcean with website up and running, reachable directly over IP address, and webserver there is also configured with your local domain name, correct?